# tableView Filter , no input in the table

Tags: uitableview, user-interface, javafx

The goal is to filter the tableView .So, when I input something to filter it works just fine , but then when I hit backspace or remove the inputs on the textField Area to go back,the tableView shows **no content in the table** ,Then I have to restart the program to reload and show the data.The data is saved and loaded from an xml file.

Also, I put an ObservaleList of contacts on the Data Class to load and store the contactList ,But on the Controller I have a similar list for the filter then the controller extends the data class to getContacts from there and add the filtredList to it. I am pretty much sure that the problem comes from that

```java
  public Data() {
      contacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   }

public ObservableList<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}
```

This is below the filter handle

```java
   public void filterContactList(String oldValue, String newValue) {
    ObservableList<Contact> filteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    if (filterInput == null || newValue.length() < oldValue.length() || newValue == null){
        contactsTable.setItems(getContacts());
    }else {
        newValue = newValue.toUpperCase();
        for (Contact contact: contactsTable.getItems()){
            String filterFirstName = contact.getFirstName();
            String filterLastName = contact.getFirstName();
            if (filterFirstName.toUpperCase().contains(newValue) || filterLastName.toUpperCase().contains(newValue)){
                filteredList.add(contact);
            }
        }
        contactsTable.setItems(filteredList);
    }
}
```

and this is the init listener

```java
filterInput.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                filterContactList((String) oldValue, (String) newValue);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor an use [`FilteredList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) for this:

```
private FilteredList<Contact> filteredContacts = new FilteredList<>(getContacts());    

...

contactsTable.setItems(filteredList);

...

public void filterContactList(String oldValue, String newValue) {
    if (newValue == null) {
        filteredContacts.setPredicate(null);
    } else {
         final String lower = newValue.toLowerCase();
         filteredContacts.setPredicte(contact -> contact.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(lower) || contact.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(lower));
    }
}
```

BTW: since this is called from a listener to `filterInput`'s `textProperty`, I removed the check for `null`.